# How I can speed up Google Apps Script code for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My code works "if AM1 > 0 show AM:AM else hide AM:AM". AM to CM
This works but is very very slow. Each step takes 1-3 seconds, and having about 53 columns, takes 50-150 seconds overall.

How I can speed this up?

[image]

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ürünler");
  var range = sheet.getRange("AP1");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var row, col;
  var data0 = ["AL:AL", "AM:AM", "AN:AN", "AO:AO", "AP:AP", "AQ:AQ", "AR:AR", "AS:AS", "AT:AT", "AU:AU",
    "AV:AV", "AW:AW", "AX:AX", "AY:AY", "AZ:AZ", "BA:BA", "BB:BB", "BC:BC", "BD:BD", "BE:BE",
    "BF:BF", "BG:BG", "BH:BH", "BI:BI", "BJ:BJ", "BK:BK", "BL:BL", "BM:BM", "BN:BN", "BO:BO",
    "BP:BP", "BQ:BQ", "BR:BR", "BS:BS", "BT:BT", "BU:BU", "BV:BV", "BW:BW", "BX:BX", "BY:BY",
    "BZ:BZ", "CA:CA", "CB:CB", "CC:CC", "CD:CD", "CE:CE", "CF:CF", "CG:CG", "CH:CH", "CI:CI",
    "CJ:CJ", "CK:CK", "CL:CL", "CM:CM", "CN:CN"];
    
  col = 38;
  for (col = 38; col < 93; col++) { //start 38 items 53
    range = sheet.getRange(1, col);
    if (range.getValue() > 0) {
      sheet.getRange(data0[col-38]).activate();
      ss.getActiveSheet().showColumns(col);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(data0[col-38]).activate();
      ss.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(col);    
    }                                      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call functions getActiveSheet(), getRange() and getValue() way too often.
Try minimizing the number of reads and writes. Consider using the getValues() method.

> You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command.

Check it out for more
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices